# ZipArchive .zip file to show all files in root

Tags: php, compression

I want the code to make all files in the tree to .zip files in the root

```
   <?PHP
// create object
$zip = new ZipArchive();

// open archive 
if ($zip->open('my-archive.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
    die ("Could not open archive");
}

// list of files to add
// list of files to add
$fileList = array(
    'im/asd.pdf',
    'im/df.pdf',
    'im/d/qoyyum.txt'
);

// add files
foreach ($fileList as $f) {
    $zip->addFile($f) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $f");   
}

// close and save archive
$zip->close();
echo "Archive created successfully.";    
?>
```

for example folder /im contains

```
/im/asd.pdf
/im/df.pdf
/im/d/qoyyum.txt
```

the 'my-archive.zip' extract should look like this

```
my-archive/asd.pdf
my-archive/df.pdf
my-archive/qoyyum.txt
```

I want to prevent the folder hierarchy when extracting the zip. so that every files should be in the root of the extracted zip folder

please suggest a tip to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a second parameter in `ZipArchive::addFile()` called `localname` (see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-addfile.php)) which lets you set the local name of the file within the zip archive. Use this to override the directory structure which is the default.

```
foreach ($fileList as $f) {
    $filename_parts = explode('/', $f);  // Split the filename up by the '/' character
    $zip->addFile($f, end($filename_parts)) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $f");   
}
```

Comment: Instead of explode and end(), you can also use [`basename()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function to get file name